# Run php script when the file is updated through python

Tags: php, python, json

I have a python program that sends an XML file to my website with FTP. I then use urlopen() from the urllib2 python library to run a php script that updates a database with the information in the XML file. This way I don't have to have the website open in a browser for the database to update when the python program sends the file. However, anyone can access that script and cause my database to update over and over again with the same information if the XML file has not changed.

Is there a python library that lets me run the php script but also send something like a JSON object with a username and password so the script first checks for that before running an update on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the requests module to send a POST request.

```
import requests


r = requests.post('https://example.com/update.php', data={'key': 'value'})
```

The requests module will raise an error if it cannot make a secure, https connection.

The keys can then be accessed in PHP using:

```
$_POST['key'];
```